# about number-theory and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Find the number of $6$ - digit numbers whose product of digits is divided by $ 4 $

---

my moves
I tried from 900000(
the number of all six-digit numbers) to subtract those options in which the product is not divisible by 4. but I couldn’t bring it to the solution. Help me figure it out ...

Comment: It might be a good idea to figure out how you can look at the digits of a number and tell whether the product of its digits is going to be divisible by $4$, _without actually calculating the product_. That's going to make counting easier.

Comment: Why not try a simpler version of the problem?  Start with two digit numbers.  Then three digits.

Comment: @Arthur well, if there are four in the required number, then we can say that the work is divisively divided by 4

Comment: @Arthur if there are 4 or 8 in the number, then we can assert that the production is divided into 4

Comment: @Arthur but this is not the only option

Comment: A quick python run gave $846874$

Comment: @Sam no, the answer is 846875.

Comment: @art1488 Are you sure, because I double checked by code and it seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, it's a good idea to count the complement. (I.e., how many $6$-digit numbers have a digit product not divisible by $4$?)

Hint:
There are two cases for counting the complement:

(1) All digits are odd.

(2) $5$ digits are odd and there is one even digit that is either $2$ or $6$.

Comment: did i count correctly?
$900000$(the number of all six-digit numbers)    (1) $5^6$(all digits are odd) (2) $(5^5*2)$(5 digits are odd and there is one even digit that is either 2 or 6.)

Comment: $(10^5*9)$-$(5^5*2)$-$5^6$ is it correct?

Comment: please answer did i count correctly?

Comment: @art1488 not quite... for $5^5\cdot 2$ you counted very specifically numbers whose **first** five digits are odd and very specifically the **last** digit is even.  You could have had the first digit be even and the remaining digits be odd, or the second digit be even and the remaining digits odd, etc...

Comment: You missed out a few.

Comment: I.e $(5^5*2)*(6)$? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct for case 2.

Comment: Thank you very much